# How can I use spark_apply() to generate combinations using combn()

Tags: r, apache-spark, apply, sparklyr

I would like to use spark to generate the output of the `combn()` function for a relatively large list of inputs (200 ish), and to varying values of `m` (2-5), however I am having trouble including this in `spark_apply()`.

A mwe of my current approach ([based on this](https://spark.rstudio.com/articles/guides-distributed-r.html)):

```
names_df <- data.frame(name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Cat"), 
                   types = c("Human", "Human", "Animal"))

combn(names_df$name, 2)

name_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc = sc,
                        x = names_df,
                        name = "name_table")

name_tbl %>%
  select(name) %>%
  spark_apply(function(e) combn(e, 2))
```

The error message output is large, but I am having trouble understanding how to use that information to refine my approach.

I expected an output such as that of the second line of the MWE. Is the problem that `combn()` is expecting a "vector source" which is not what I am providing by `select()`? Or is it that select is not returning "An object (usually a spark_tbl) coercable to a Spark DataFrame"? Either way, is there a method I can use to achieve the desired result?

I have also tried this in an attempt with no success:

```
name_tbl %>%
  select(name) %>% # removing this also doesn't work
  spark_apply(function(e) combn(e$name, 2))
```

EDIT: so `expand.grid` works fine, which suggests to me that there is some issue with the return of `combn` not being able to be coerced into a data.frame.

Working `expand.grid`:

```
name_tbl %>%
  spark_apply(function(e) expand.grid(e))
```

EDIT 2:

Having more closely read the documentation, I have now also tried coercing the function into a data.frame as it says:

> Your R function should be designed to operate on an R data frame. The R function passed to spark_apply expects a DataFrame and will return an object that can be cast as a DataFrame.

However, the following are also unsuccessful:

```
name_tbl %>%
  spark_apply(function(e) data.frame(combn(e$name, 2)))

name_tbl %>%
  select(name) %>%
  spark_apply(function(e) data.frame(combn(e, 2)))
```

Comment: I've just located the `expand.grid()` function. In this specific case I don't think I need it, but I expect I will for the next section of work I need to do. I would be interested if there is an example of using spark to apply that as well if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `combn()` does not work properly with factors, code also needs named columns, as in:

```
name_tbl %>%
  spark_apply(
    function(e) data.frame(combn(as.character(e$name), 2)),
    names = c("1", "2", "3")
  )

# Source:   table<sparklyr_tmp_626bc0dd927> [?? x 3]
# Database: spark_connection
    `1`   `2`   `3`
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Alice Alice   Bob
2   Bob   Cat   Cat
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and the work I know you've done on the project. A small extension question as I hadn't realised that the `names` argument was needed. Why is it required, and how would you suggest supplying it values when the length of the output is very large? I've trialled successfully `as.character(c(1:choose(3, 2)))`. Is there anything more appropriate?

Comment: Additionally, from the docs for `combn`: "Factors x are accepted from R 3.1.0 (although coincidentally they worked for simplify = FALSE in earlier versions). " So do you mean that the documentation is incorrect/incomplete, or that there is something going on behind the scenes on the spark side that prevents it using factors?

Comment: Right, generating the names as you suggest seems reasonable. Regarding, `combn` it does support factors, I should have said that using factors as inputs results in factors as output, forcing `as.character` makes the result of `combn` become a `matrix` which can be wrapped as `data.frame`. We need to make sure that `spark_apply()` function returns a data frame, there might be other (better?) ways of achieving this for `combn`.

Comment: Having used this IRL on a larger scale problem (combinations of a list of 180 strings) I wondered if there was any advice about having the process distributed that I was missing? It appeared that the processing was heavily biased to the node running rstudio.

Comment: @DaveRGP The algorithm R uses for generating combinations is strictly serial (see the while loop in the center of the function).  I haven't seen one that operates in parallel/distributed.

Comment: You are correct. @russellpierce, once I implmented the functional recommendations here the process ran without error. However on distributing the data set across multiple machines subsequent checks proved that the function had run within each machine but not across it i.e. machine one has a,b,c machine 2 has d,e,f. The process returns ab, ac,bc, de,df,ef but not ad,ae or af. I left the answers marked as correct at it fixed the technical problem of return, however I should have updated this post. Apologies.