# Count by vector of multiple columns in sparklyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550701/how-can-i-use-spark-apply-to-generate-combinations-using-combn) I had some good help to generate possible combinations of a set or variables.

Assume the output of that process is

```
combo_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc = sc,
                     x = data.frame(
                       combo_id = c("combo1", "combo2", "combo3"),
                       selection_1 = c("Alice", "Alice", "Bob"),
                       selection_2 = c("Bob", "Cat", "Cat")
                     ),
                     name = "combo_table")
```

This is a tbl reference to a spark data frame object with two columns, each representing a selection of 2 values from a list of 3 (Alice, Bob, Cat), that could be imagined as 3 members of a household.

Now there is also a spark data frame with a binary encoding indicating a 1 if the member of the house was in the house, and 0 where they were not.

```
obs_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc = sc,
                   x = data.frame(
                     obs_day = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"),
                     Alice = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
                     Bob = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     Cat = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
                   ),
                   name = "obs_table")
```

I can relatively simply check if a specific pair were present in the house with this code:

```
obs_tbl %>%
  group_by(Alice, Bob) %>%
  summarise(n())
```

However, there are 2 flaws with this approach.

1. Each pair is being put in manually, when every combination I need to check is already in `combo_tbl`.
2. The output automatically outputs the intersection of every combination. i.e. I get the count of values where both Alice and Bob == 1, but also where Alice ==1 and Bob == 0, Alice == 0 and Bob ==1, etc.

The ideal end result would be an output like so:

```
Alice | Bob | 2
Alice | Cat | 2
Bob   | Cat | 2
```

i.e. The count of co-habitation days per pair.

A perfect solution would allow simple modification to change the number of selection within the combination to increase. i.e. each combo_id may have 3 or greater selections, from a larger list than the one given.

So, is it possible on sparklyr to pass a vector of pairs that are iterated through?
How do I only check for where both of my selections are present? Instead of a vectorised `group_by` should I use a vectorised `filter`?

I've read about quosures and standard evaluation in the tidyverse. Is that the solution to this if running locally? And if so is this supported by spark?

**For reference**, I have a relatively similar solution using data.table that can be run on a single-machine, non-spark context. Some pseudo code:

```
combo_dt[, obs_dt[get(tolower(selection_1)) == "1" &
                  get(tolower(selection_2)) == "1"
                          , .N], by = combo_id]
```

This nested process effectively splits each combination into it's own sub-table: `by = combo_id`, and then for that sub-table filters where `selection_1` and `selection_2` are 1, and then applies `.N` to count the rows in that sub-table, and then aggregates the output.